# Multiple file upload using Quarkus and RestEasy

Tags: java, file-upload, resteasy, quarkus

I am trying to set up an endpoint that allows multiple file upload, along other form data. Consider this like a create product page, where you would have a couple of product images but also other information. Ideally I want to map the request to a POJO

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/product/create")
public Response createProduct(@MultipartForm CreateProductRequest req)  {
```

And the POJO:

```
@Data
public class CreateProductRequest {

@FormParam("name")
private String name;

@FormParam("description")
private String description;

@FormParam("tags")
private List<String> tags; 

@FormParam("img")
@PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
private List<InputStream> img; //Ideally I could use an object such as MultipartFile 
                               //that would give me access to the filename and MIME type

}
```

But this doesn't work, I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY007545: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader for media type:
image&#x2F;jpeg;charset=UTF-8 and class type java.util.List
```

If I remove the `List`, it works fine.

And it seems its the same issue with `List<String> tags`

Which throws :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY007545: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader for media 
type: text&#x2F;plain;charset=UTF-8 and class type java.util.List
```

I've seen workarounds using `MultipartFormDataInput` but i would really like to avoid that since the request obj is pretty large, and mapping it by hand would be very tedious and error prone.

I am running Java 11, Quarkus 1.11.1.Final

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I recently had the same issue and I was wondering if there is a different approach than the one geoand mentions.

Answer (score 0):

POJOs annotated with `@MultipartForm` don't support using files with `List`

Comment: Definitely seems so but, are there any alternatives to mapping a Multipart Request with several files to a POJO ?

Comment: You need to specify each file as a separate field